# os.rename error: The System Cannot Find The Path Specified

Tags: python, string

I need to apply a new naming convention to files across a lot of subdirectories. For example, the files in one subdirectory might be:

- *ABC (E) String of Text.txt*
- *ABC (E) String of Text.ocr.txt*
- *ABC (E) String of Text.pdf*

They need to all be renamed to follow this convention:

- *ABC String of Text (E).txt*
- *ABC String of Text (E).ocr.txt*
- *ABC String of Text (E).pdf*

### Here's what I've got so far...

---

```
import os, re

regex = re.compile('\s\([a-zA-Z]+\)')

path = os.path.expanduser('~/Google Drive/Directory/Subdirectory/')

for files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        strname = str(name)
        oldName = os.path.join(path,strname)
        if(regex.search(strname)):
            # identifying the token that needs shuffling
            token = regex.findall(oldName)
            # remove the token
            removed = (regex.split(oldName)[0] + ' ' +
                       regex.split(oldName)[1].strip())
            print removed # this is where everything goes wrong
            # remove the file extension
            split = removed.split('.')
            # insert the token at the end of the filename
            reformatted = split[0] + token[0]
            # reinsert the file extension
            for i in range(1,len(split)):
                reformatted += '.' + split[i]
            os.rename(oldName,reformatted)
```

---

It ends up trying to rename the files by pulling a substring from a list of files in the directory, but includes list-related characters like "[" and "'", resulting in WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified.

Example:

> C:\Users\Me/Google Drive/Directory/Subdirectory/['ABC String of Text.txt', 'ABC

My hope is that someone can see what I'm trying to accomplish and point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `os.walk` which doesn't do what you want for the way you're using it: see https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either
>   top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at
>   directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath,
>   dirnames, filenames).

Perhaps you mean to do something like:

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        oldName = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
        ...
```

Comment: This was perfect; spot on. My script runs beautifully now. Thank you so much.